# Exclude IE cookie from UWF in windows

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, cookies, uwf

I have set up the UWF on C: and excluded several folders that should be writable for my setup to work. Additionally I have an Internet Explorer cookie that is saved locally. According to Internet Options-> Browsing History -> Settings -> View Files ending up at C:\Users<Name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache where there are cooke: files. But they only contain: "Cookies are no longer stored in files. Please use Internet*Cookie * APIs to access cookies."

When i exclude the whole INetCache folder from UWF my windows startup pops up a few errors that some .exe coulnt be started the right way. And excluding a single file produces: "Error: Could not exclude "" by Unified Write Filter (0x80004005)."
Most likely because of the "/" at the end.

But what is the best way to exclude that one cookie for Internet Explorer from the UWF and where is it located if not in the path specified above?
Also while searching for the location it seems various people haven't found the location either: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/ie11-normal-cookies-are-gone-since-creators-fall/7f2b38a0-aeaf-4c4b-a53f-dd438fdc20cd?page=1

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
uwfmgr file add-exclusion C:\Users\User\Desktop
```

command with your `pfad`, if you haven't.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1204248)

Comment: It was an answer, no question. 

Comment: The first sentence ends with a `?`, which is a question. The 2nd also doesn't sound convincing. Answers should spread knowledge, not try to obtain it from the question author.